# Juju deploy issue : Connection was refused by other side

Tags: juju, maas

I am trying to deploy MAAS + JUJU on a 10 node infrastructure.

I have easily configured MAAS (13.04 LTS) on one node and queued 6 other nodes,

Also have got Juju installed on the MAAS node,

Now the issue is when I deploy wordpress as suggested in example, it gets initiated fine but stays pending because of connection time out issue on node1,

```
2013-05-29 00:43:10,899: juju.agents.machine@DEBUG: Units changed old:set([]) new:set(['wordpress/9'])
2013-05-29 00:43:10,899: juju.agents.machine@DEBUG: Starting service unit: wordpress/9 ...
2013-05-29 00:43:11,028: unit.deploy@DEBUG: Downloading charm cs:precise/wordpress-15 to /var/lib/juju/charms
2013-05-29 00:43:11,071: juju.agents.machine@ERROR: Error starting unit: wordpress/9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/agents/machine.py", line 97, in watch_service_units
    yield self.unit_deployer.start_service_unit(unit_name)
ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

========================================================

```
maasadmin@boxone:~$ juju -v status
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: node3.master
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-f87f30e6-c788-11e2-a0dd-984be17f8190/
    instance-state: unknown
  1:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: node1.master
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-aa3eaf8e-c787-11e2-b3fd-984be17f8190/
    instance-state: unknown
services:
  wordpress:
    charm: cs:precise/wordpress-15
    relations:
      loadbalancer:
      - wordpress
    units:
      wordpress/9:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 1
        public-address: null
2013-05-29 01:07:43,185 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
```

Any help on this would be great

Answer (score 3):

I see that you're still using the old Py-Juju, which is no longer being supported or developed. Please switch to the newer Juju-Core instead.

Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install juju-core
```

Reboot and see if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

[Py-Juju](https://launchpad.net/juju) is no longer actively developed or supported. Please try using [Juju-Core](https://launchpad.net/juju-core) instead and see if your issue is still present.

Comment: To use juju-core (the new version of juju that doesn't require python) do this: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable &&
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju-core